# panic: Error while trying to create dir if missing: mkdir /var/hyperledger: permission denied

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm following this guide
https://github.com/ITPeople-Blockchain/auction
after the make native command, I execute the next command ./orderer but I received the following error:

> panic: Error while trying to create dir if missing: mkdir /var/hyperledger: permission denied

shell log:

> 2017-07-06 14:50:11.556 CEST [orderer/main] main -> INFO 001 Starting orderer:
>    Version: 1.0.0-rc2-snapshot-a0afe19a
>    Go version: go1.8.3
>    OS/Arch: linux/amd64
>      panic: Error while trying to create dir if missing: mkdir /var/hyperledger: permission denied
>
> goroutine 1 [running]:
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/util/leveldbhelper.(*DB).Open(0xc42034b480)
>       /home/user/work/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/util/leveldbhelper/leveldb_helper.go:84 +0x315
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/util/leveldbhelper.NewProvider(0xc4203583c0, 0xc4203583c0)
>       /home/user/work/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/util/leveldbhelper/leveldb_provider.go:40 +0x11b
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage.NewProvider(0xc420355da0, 0xc420355dc0, 0xc4203583a0, 0xc420167c50)
>       /home/user/work/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage/fs_blockstore_provider.go:34 +0x85
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/ledger/file.New(0xc4201ee480, 0x23, 0x2, 0x2)
>       /home/user/work/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/ledger/file/factory.go:75 +0xf7
>   main.createLedgerFactory(0xc4201c06c0, 0x870ad0, 0xc4200ec8c0, 0xc42033e6c0, 0x0)
>       /home/user/work/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/util.go:42 +0x2c3
>   main.initializeMultiChainManager(0xc4201c06c0, 0x11a18a0, 0x11f2e40, 0xc4201d45d0, 0x1)
>       /home/user/work/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/main.go:207 +0x43
>   main.main()
>       /home/user/work/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/main.go:75 +0x37f

Comment: But, If I use the command "sudo ./orderer", I received the following error:         CEST [orderer/localconfig] Load -> CRIT 002 Error reading configuration: Unsupported Config Type ""panic: Error reading configuration:Unsupported Config Type ""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/hyperledger/production
sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) /var/hyperledger
```

Comment: Help? Someone has a solution? Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

You could change the **fileSystemPath** in core.yaml from "/var/hyperledger/production" to a place that does not need a sudo permission. Such as "/tmp/hyperledger/production"